# Showing text instead of an alert-box

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm trying to show an error saying that the user needs to enter a valid email address. At the moment I have show an alert but I would like to have a text underneath the textbox instead. This is my jQuery:

```
var email = $.trim($("#email").val());

if(email == "" || !isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
    alert('enter valid email');
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need something like this.

```
var email = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#email").val());
    if(email == "" || !isValidEmailAddress(email)){
        jQuery('#email_error').show();
        return false;
    }
```

And in the HTML something like:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="email" name="email" />
<div style="display:none" class="error" id="email_error">Your email is incorrectly formatted</div>
```

You could of course change the class in the error field as a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create an empty span element after the field and insert any error message into that. This way, you can have various error messages, for example invalid email, no email entered etc.

```
var email = jQuery.trim(jQuery("#email").val()),
    errorText;

if(email === ""){
  errorText = "Please enter an address";
} else if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)){
  errorText = "Address is invalid";
}

if (errorText){
  jQuery('#email_error').text(errorText);
  return false;
}
```

A span will also display inline, so the message appears right next to the field.